# Does Barcode/Magswipe Track data contains photo/image information on Driving License?

Tags: barcode, magnetic-cards, pdf417

In the US does the PDF417 format for identification cards store image/photo information in the barcode/magswipe tracks?
Can we extract that information if it is available?

Comment: Think how many bits a barcode could hold !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photo is going to take many kilobytes to have any decent resolution. A single PDF417 can hold a little over 1.5k. A magstripe even less.

There isn't a photo in either data store.